# Adding brackets to OR_LIKE query on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have difficulty to adding brackets to my query. My query consists of `OR`, `AND` and `LIKE`. This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`vendor`) JOIN `vendor_detail` ON `vendor`.`id_vendor`
= `vendor_detail`.`id_vendor` JOIN `klasifikasi` ON `vendor_detail`.`id_klasifikasi` = `klasifikasi`.`id_klasifikasi`
WHERE `vendor_detail`.`id_klasifikasi` = 'K0002' AND
`vendor`.`st_aktif` = 1 AND (`vendor`.`id_vendor` LIKE '%eka%' OR
`vendor`.`nama_vendor` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`alamat` LIKE '%eka%'
OR `vendor`.`telp` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`mobile` LIKE '%eka%' OR
`vendor`.`fax` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`cp` LIKE '%eka%' OR
`vendor`.`telp_cp` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`catatan` LIKE '%eka%' OR
`vendor`.`email` LIKE '%eka%')
```

As you can see I am adding brackets after `vendor.st_aktif = 1 AND` and in the last line of my query.
How can I implement above query to Code Igniter Active Records?
This is my current CI AR:

```
function src_vendor_by_name($src_nama,$src_kls){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('vendor');
    $this->db->join('vendor_detail', 'vendor.id_vendor = vendor_detail.id_vendor');
    $this->db->join('klasifikasi', 'vendor_detail.id_klasifikasi = klasifikasi.id_klasifikasi');
    $this->db->where('vendor_detail.id_dklasifikasi', $src_kls);
    $this->db->where('vendor.st_aktif', 1);

    if($src_nama != "")
    { 
        $this->db->or_like('vendor.id_vendor',$src_nama);
        $this->db->or_like('vendor.nama_vendor',$src_nama);
        $this->db->or_like('vendor.alamat',$src_nama);
        $this->db->or_like('vendor.telp',$src_nama);
        $this->db->or_like('vendor.mobile',$src_nama);
        $this->db->or_like('vendor.fax',$src_nama);
        $this->db->or_like('vendor.cp',$src_nama);
        $this->db->or_like('vendor.telp_cp',$src_nama);
        $this->db->or_like('vendor.catatan',$src_nama);
        $this->db->or_like('vendor.email',$src_nama);
    }

    return $this->db->get()->result_array(); 
}
```

Comment: why don't you are using custom query

Comment: is that safe? I am not quite sure if it's not active records

Comment: AR doesn't support nested `WHERE` clauses AFAIK, so you have to fall back to using raw SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think pure CodeIgniter will allow you to do a nested `WHERE` clause the way you want to do it.  But one option is to use a custom string:

```
$where  = "(`vendor`.`id_vendor` LIKE '%eka%' OR ";
$where .= "`vendor`.`nama_vendor` LIKE '%eka%' OR";
$where .= "`vendor`.`alamat` LIKE '%eka%' OR ";
$where .= "`vendor`.`telp` LIKE '%eka%' OR ";
$where .= "`vendor`.`mobile` LIKE '%eka%' OR ";
$where .= "`vendor`.`fax` LIKE '%eka%' OR ";
$where .= "`vendor`.`cp` LIKE '%eka%' OR ";
$where .= "`vendor`.`telp_cp` LIKE '%eka%' OR ";
$where .= "`vendor`.`catatan` LIKE '%eka%' OR ";
$where .= "`vendor`.`email` LIKE '%eka%')";
$this->db->where($where);
```

There is something called [IgnitedQuery](https://app.assembla.com/wiki/show/IgnitedRecord/IgnitedQuery) which appears to supports nested `WHERE` statements.

Comment: Is it safe? and where are the brackets? I don't see any brackets added.

Comment: It should be safe.  The brackets are implicit, because this entire `WHERE` condition would be ANDed to the rest of your expression, which is the logic you seem to want.

Comment: It's not working. When I accidentally erroring my model to see the query, no brackets are added

Comment: the function behaves like no brackets are added

Comment: @Simba Then just add parentheses (not brackets) to the raw `WHERE` clause as I have just done above.

Answer (score 18):

[Query grouping](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping) allows you to create groups of WHERE clauses by enclosing them in parentheses. This will allow you to create queries with complex WHERE clauses.

**$this->db->group_start()**
Starts a new group by adding an opening parenthesis to the WHERE clause of the query.

**$this->db->group_end()**
Ends the current group by adding an closing parenthesis to the WHERE clause of the query.

```
function src_vendor_by_name($src_nama,$src_kls){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('vendor');
$this->db->join('vendor_detail', 'vendor.id_vendor = vendor_detail.id_vendor');
$this->db->join('klasifikasi', 'vendor_detail.id_klasifikasi = klasifikasi.id_klasifikasi');
$this->db->where('vendor_detail.id_dklasifikasi', $src_kls);
$this->db->where('vendor.st_aktif', 1);

if($src_nama != "")
{ 
    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->or_like('vendor.id_vendor',$src_nama);
    $this->db->or_like('vendor.nama_vendor',$src_nama);
    $this->db->or_like('vendor.alamat',$src_nama);
    $this->db->or_like('vendor.telp',$src_nama);
    $this->db->or_like('vendor.mobile',$src_nama);
    $this->db->or_like('vendor.fax',$src_nama);
    $this->db->or_like('vendor.cp',$src_nama);
    $this->db->or_like('vendor.telp_cp',$src_nama);
    $this->db->or_like('vendor.catatan',$src_nama);
    $this->db->or_like('vendor.email',$src_nama);
    $this->db->group_end();
}

return $this->db->get()->result_array(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 6):

Simply use:

$this->db->group_start()

$this->db->group_end()

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can make query grouping.
as 
http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Answer (score 0):

Check the condition first '%eka%'(Var)

```
If('%eka%' != ''){
    $where  = "(`vendor`.`id_vendor` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`nama_vendor` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`alamat` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`telp` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`mobile` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`fax` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`cp` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`telp_cp` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`catatan` LIKE '%eka%' OR `vendor`.`email` LIKE '%eka%')";
    $this->db->where($where);
}
```